# Duplicate object in SVF converted from linked revit

Tags: autodesk-forge, autodesk-viewer

I am trying to convert a SVF using linked Revit files. I uploaded a zip to model derivative API which contains all the Revit files.

After conversion, the revit files are combined into one single SVF, but I discovered that at least some of the objects might be duplicated in a weird way.

For example, I have an object which have an unique attribute defined. When I select that object, I can see its position inside the model browser, as well as its properties. (Screenshot 1)[image: Screenshot 1]

When I try to search in the whole model using that unique attribute, I discovered that another object has the same attribute and properties. When I try to select it using its dbId, I found that the object is invisible in the model, and it does not show where does it belong inside the model browser. (Screenshot 2)
[image: Screenshot 2]
Any idea why is there a duplicated object inside the SVF? Thanks.

Comment: Can you send the model archive to forge.help@autodesk.com (via a sharing service like weTransfer/Dropbox/GDrive) if possible so we can try replicate the issue? Along with your translation job payload?

Comment: I've just send a e-mail to forge.help@autodesk.com with the required information. Kindly please help to check, Thanks!